# How can I apply a inline Cufon styling in an email?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use inline styling for Cufon for an HTML email. Is there a way to implement a Cufon inline style?

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'Cuprum';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Cuprum'), local('Cuprum-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/cuprum/v4/sp1_LTSOMWWV0K5VTuZzvQ.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cuprum';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Cuprum Bold'), local('Cuprum-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/cuprum/v4/SfDyn5tWOk7I1we45jpLKz8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
```

Comment: can you give me your full code or give me jsfiddle.

Comment: It's not possible in an email. Images are your best bet. HTML emails are quite far behind the web.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but you can't use Cufon in emails. HTML emails are like the web was 8 years ago or so. To get decent cross email browser results you're better off keeping things simple and using images for font replacement and dare I say it, even using tables for the layout.

This is an excellent resource for this. It clearly lays out what you can and can't do.

http://www.emailology.org/